# What changes need to make to SQL Server database for financial year changes?

Tags: sql-server

I have a software which uses VB.NET and SQL Server. The software works fine but the problem if consider it is new financial year then for new year all the bills should start from 1.

Currently all bills are stored in a database table, not sure how can this been done. If I move those entries from table to another temporary table then counting starts from one but all my functions that are dependent on that table show incorrect output.

Or is there any alternative way for managing software which must consider financial year change?

Comment: If you need control over primary key values, don't idea DB-generated value like IDENTITY. Generate your own in your application biz logic.

Comment: You should have WorkPeriods table which contains valid periods for your logic. And in all operational tables you then have WorkPerionID, SomeId as composite primary key. SomeId can be sequential object that you will reset when new period starts.

Answer (score 0):

an option is to do a row number over a partition. your query would look something like

```
SELECT billName,
billAmmount,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
    ORDER BY billDate 
    PARTITION BY (CAST((DATEADD *the offset from calendar year start to fiscal year start* billDate) AS YEAR) 
) AS billNum
FROM billsTable
```

what this is doing is counting rows in order of bill date, and restarting the count at one every time the fiscal year is hit. this number will be returned as billNum.

the section

```
(DATEADD *the offset from calendar year start to fiscal year start* billDate)
```

is the most important part here. as it converts fiscal years into calendar years. then you must decide if the converted year is that year and the year prior, or that year and the year after. E.g. if the converted year is 2015, does that mean fiscal year 2015-2016 or fiscal year 2014-2015. it just depends on which direction you convert it in the DATEADD.